# Multiple calls next value for sequence at same time

Tags: sql, database, sequences

I have table named QuestionRecords in MSSQL. And i have a stored procedure that retrives next value for my sequence.  I want generate question number for each questions by using this stored procedure. But i have a question. What will be do, is more than 100 customers use my application and call my procedure at same time. Will sequence numbers crash?

Thanx for your answers.

Comment: It will be hard to say without seeing your stored procedure.

Comment: My procedure only contains a statement that return next value for sequence.

Comment: No. In any case the sequence numbers couldn't be crashed. Sequence is smart enough to generate numbers in such a way that 100s of people can use it at same time.